# Modifying backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, for-loop, underscore.js

I have a collection which has collection of models. I have to get each model and set some more properties to that before submitting to the server.

how to  do this using backbone.?

**UPDATE :**

this is what i tried to print the model if it prints wanted to try with `set` property of model but it was giving me `uncaught typeerror cannot call method 'each' of undefined`:

```
covertInvestmentJournal:function(){
            this.investmentTransactionsCollection.each(function(model){
                  console.log(model); 
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved my problem :

```
for (var i = 0, l = investmentTransactionsCollection.length; i < l; i++) {
                investmentTransactionsCollection.models[i].set({securityName:$('#security-name').val()});
                investmentTransactionsCollection.models[i].set({valueDate:DateUtils.formatAsYMD($('#value-date'))});
                investmentTransactionsCollection.models[i].set({adjustmentType:$('#adjustment-type').val()});
                investmentTransactionsCollection.models[i].set({assetClass:$('#assetclass').val()});
                investmentTransactionsCollection.models[i].set({currency:$('#currency').val()});
            }
```